# C# P/Invoke for keyboard layout and compiler warnings

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm not used to P/Invoke but I should declare a couple of WinAPI functions for getting or setting the keyboard layout. I declared the functions like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern long LoadKeyboardLayout(
    string pwszKLID,    // input locale identifier
    uint Flags          // input locale identifier options
    );

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(
    StringBuilder pwszKLID  //[out] string that receives the name of the locale identifier
    );
```

But when I compile this (in a C# WPF application) I get the warnings:

**CA1901**
Microsoft.Portability
As it is declared in your code, the return type of P/Invoke 
will be 4 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. 
This is not correct, as the actual native declaration of 
this API indicates it should be 8 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. 
Consult the MSDN Platform SDK documentation for help determining 
what data type should be used instead of 'long'.

and (I suppose this is of less concern as keyboard layout names are just digits):

**CA2101**
Microsoft.Globalization
To reduce security risk, marshal parameter 'pwszKLID' as Unicode, by setting DllImport.CharSet to CharSet.Unicode, or by explicitly marshaling the parameter as UnmanagedType.LPWStr. If you need to marshal this string as ANSI or system-dependent, specify MarshalAs explicitly, and set BestFitMapping=false; for added security, also set ThrowOnUnmappableChar=true.

I tried using IntPtr for the first warning, but this does not solve the issue. Could anyone help by pointing me to the correct form for these declarations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following declarations:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(
    string pwszKLID,    // input locale identifier
    uint Flags          // input locale identifier options
    );

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetKeyboardLayoutName(
    StringBuilder pwszKLID  //[out] string that receives the name of the locale identifier
    );
```

The `CharSet` specification will clear up CA2101.  Adjusting the returns of both methods to the correct return types and adding the `MarshalAs` for the return on the `GetKeyboardLayoutName` will clear up the CA1901.

Comment: Default marshalling for C# `bool` is as Windows `BOOL`. Hence the MarshalAs is not needed.

Comment: @David, I had originally left it as such, but with the Code Analysis turned on as Naftis has which is causing the warnings, it did generate a warning for me.  Hence the addition of the MarshalAs.

Answer (score 0):

LoadKeyboardLayout returns HKL, which is actually void*.

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HKL;
```

GetKeyboardLayoutName returns BOOL, which is actually 32-bit int. So, you need to define 
LoadKeyboardLayout return type as IntPtr, and GetKeyboardLayoutName return type as int.

Comment: Thanks this worked for the 1st warning! As for the 2nd I think I can safely ignore it...